# What is the difference between urls with and without www?

Tags: dns

I know very basics of how DNS works.
I am confused about what happens in the browser, DNS server, and hosting server when I type

`www.google.com` vs `google.com`

I see that the browser changes `google.com` and `www.google.com` to the same thing `https://www.google.com`. is this only because google has `cname` record that points `www.google.com` to `google.com`?

is `www.sld.tld` and `sld.tld` always same for every top-level domain and second level domain?

is there any example where `www.sld.tld` and `sld.tld` give different result in the browser?

if they are always same why convert `sld.tld` to `www.sld.tld` when I type in the browser why not always simply use `sld.tld` only instead?

Comment: `www` is also a subdomain and act different than non www URLs.

Comment: There is nothing specific about `www`, it is just a human convention. The DNS just maps names to IP addresses, then the webserver at the end can totally provide different content for `example.com` and `www.example.com` if so configured... but that might certainly confuse people. `www` is just the result of very old design decisions, in a time where one server = one service, but since then lots of possible type of indirection happened, including `SRV` records in the DNS that unfortunately web browsers do not follow. But the new `SVCB` and `HTTPS` records might change all of that.